# Identify column name information from table schema

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

I have multiple tables with with varying names for the same piece of data. For example, `day` vs `business_day`. I'd like to identify what column names exist for which table. I think this can be done using schema information, but I'm not familiar with it.

For simplicity, the tables below are 3 separate tables with these column names.

`table_1`

```
day    city  weather
```

`table_2`

```
business_day location  status
```

`table_3`

```
day   city  rain
```

Where `day` and `business_day` and `city` and `location` are the same piece of information, but unfortunately different naming conventions so I wouldn't be able to use the same selection criteria in a `WHERE` clause. I'd like to search the table information to see which tables have `day` or `business_day` and `city` or `location`. The other columns are not important to me in this example. How can I identify table information in this way?

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Please remove the irrelevant tag (unless you want solutions for both). Also, you seem to know that `information_schema` has something to do with the answer; did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL and Postgres you can use

MySQL [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html)
Postgres [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/infoschema-columns.html)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, table_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  AND column_name LIKE 'day' OR column_name LIKE 'business_day'
```

Comment: `column_name LIKE 'day'` -- really? Please don't make me downvote your answer.

Comment: what do you mean, he asked for a solution and day is a string so if he has such a cplumn, so be it neither mysql nor postgres will thrw an error

Comment: In the absence of wildcard symbols `column_name LIKE 'day'` is equivalent to `column_name = 'day'`, so why did you choose the `LIKE` predicate?

Comment: Because i use in most cases `LIKE` with stirngs and rarely `=`

Comment: That's a good reason to downvote then, thank you.